# How to set up constraints in Xcode 6 (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, constraints

I was wondering, how do I set up auto layout for Objective-C in Xcode 6. Nothing seems to work. Deployment targets are 6.0-8.3

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'set up'? It should be enabled by default.

Comment: define 'nothing? you haven't at all described the problem

Comment: The text boxes are moved all around, even through I tried to constrain them. As far as "nothing", I went into the constraint menu and it wasn't able to get anything to work. I tried manually adding constraints, and I also tried to check the appropriate buttons in order to constrain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the option "use auto layout" in the xib or story-board, like this: http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Enable-autolayout.png

Comment: that is checked. Changing the title to constraints because it fits better.

Comment: So, you can follow this tutorial: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/autolayout-xcode6/